# What math Adobe After Effects uses for animation?

Tags: curve, spline, after-effects

I need to recreate animation curves from adobe after effects in my program.

For instance, the red curve on this chart (with corresponding speed chart in white):
[image: animation chart]

I tried to represent it with hermite spline using the value and speed extracted from both ends of the curve.
But since AE curve has the additional "influence" parameters my hermite spline failed to reproduce the result.

What kind of curves do they use?
It doesn't look like a cubic spline.

Answer (score -1):

After Effects' graph editor uses Bezier curves, which use influence points (attached to handles for better visual connection) to influence the curve's path between keyframes.

[Control points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkd23.png)

A Bezier curve can be described using a mathematical formula:  Given the coordinates of control points P<sub>i</sub>: the first control point has coordinates P<sub>1</sub> = (x<sub>1</sub>, y<sub>1</sub>), the second: P<sub>2</sub> = (x<sub>2</sub>, y<sub>2</sub>), and so on, the curve coordinates are described by the equation that depends on the parameter t from the segment [0,1].

For 4 control points:

P = (1−t)<sup>3</sup>P<sub>1</sub> + 3(1−t)<sup>2</sup>tP<sub>2</sub> +3(1−t)t<sup>2</sup>P<sub>3</sub> + t<sup>3</sup>P<sub>4</sub>

Lots more detail about Bezier curves can be found here:
https://javascript.info/bezier-curve

Comment: I'm not sure that this is the case. First, because the hermite spline - which is just another physical meaning of bezier curve - don't match the observation. Second, this way control points for bezier are 2D: time + value. And because bezier takes length **at curve** as input It means that it will return time and value as output. So I need to "reverse" the bezier formula to get value at a given time. Which is very uncommon way to do curves. So, are You **sure** about this?